Chinese comedy movie
I've watched it when I was little. It was an Asian comedy particularly a Chinese film. All I can remember is that there was one scene where they took turns being tied up with the female lead just to take a chance on her. The men were pretending to be robbers and tied one of them with the woman and they did this until all of them got a chance to be tied up with the woman.

it looks like you really hate uppercased letters )))

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add any details that may help identification. When did you watch this? What time was it likely from? Any other plot details or descriptions you can give?

That's My Lucky Stars (1985):

A corrupt Hong Kong cop (Lam Ching Ying) flees to Tokyo to join his
  fellow mobsters, [...] Two loyal cops, Ricky (Yuen Biao) and Muscle
  (Jackie Chan), travel there to apprehend him and uncover the mobsters’
  lair, but Ricky is kidnapped in a fight.
Muscle goes into hiding and calls his supervisor to send help; [...]
  Muscle asks to send his orphanage friends, nicknamed the Five Lucky
  Stars, over. The supervisor agrees and collects the five friends, who
  are all either petty criminals or low-wage workers. 
[...] the supervisor teams them up with a rookie policewoman,
  Swordflower, who becomes an object of lustful target to the five [...]

There is a short shot of the scene in the trailer.
  
   (the guys dress up as ninjas and take turns getting tied to the woman they have a crush on)

Thanks oliver_c. I've been looking for this for a long time.
